# Detecting Mobile vs. Tablet vs. Desktop Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am running into some issues determining the type of browser using Javascript. My current method is to capture the screen width and height and determine the type of browser based on pixel sizes.

I figured I could assume that any screen width under 768 would be mobile, anything under 1024 tablet, and anything above that a desktop.

I've started testing on a few devices I can actually get my hands on and the results are much different. For instance on an android (Droid Bionic to be exact though it doesn't  matter much) its returning a width of 980 regardless if the device is in landscape or portrait mode. This is much higher than I assumed.

Currently I am using document.documentElement.clientWidth to determine the width but I have tried other approaches such as window.innerWidth as well.

I guess what I am trying to get at is a question that has been asked many of times and I thought I had a pretty clear answer to. Apparently it might be time for a refresh on proper browser/device detection. So what is the most effective way to determine the actual size of the device I am on?

**UPDATE:**
It seems as if mobile browsers are actually taking it upon themselves to decide how to display my application. And in fact they are, but there is a way to stop it. See answer. Fortunately this means that the standard feature detection methods we are used to are still the best way to determine the device you are using.

Comment: *Why* are you doing that detection ? If you need to adapt due to a certain feature of desktop or tablet, then you'd better test for the presence of this feature.

Comment: Is it necessary to do it with javascript only.. I mean the same thing can be achieved by CSS Media query...

Comment: Mobile browsers will report a different screen size from the actual size unless you use the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) meta tag.

Comment: What exactly is the end goal? another alternative is to use CSS media queries and use javascript based on that.

Comment: I use media queries in each case I can...however there are some circumstances that I have to do javascript detection such as showing specific items etc. I think the key here is the viewport tag that dagg mentioned. I'll look into that.

Comment: @Dagg. Your suggestion worked! I had no idea we had to set a meta tag to stop browsers from doing their own magic on a site. I guess it makes sense though since most of the web has not yet caught up to responsive. I wish you would make your comment an answer or sorts so I could accept it.

Comment: fwiw the [modernizr misc. tests](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-misc) include a test for touch events which will be most mobile devices these days

Comment: The problem with detecting touch is that more and more devices are becoming touch. In fact almost every new windows laptop has touch screen. Even if you are using a desktop without a touchscreen, but the browser supports touch events the test will pass.

Comment: @ryandlf you will have real problems if you try to detect if it is a tablet, phone or laptop/desktop by resolution. my laptop is at `1440x900`,  the secondary display of my desktop where i most of the time open webpages is also around this resolution but rotated `900x1440`. and my tablet has a larger resolution then `1440x900`.

Comment: Agreed, but I use very general rules such as < 800 is phone etc. I guess when I say mobile vs tablet I just mean the typical screen size. If a laptop has really low resolution and matches a typical iPad then I still want to display the tablet version of the site on the laptop. Hope that makes sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ryandlf, sorry for being lazy... your own answer looks good though, you should accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Dagg Nabbit's comment on the question:

It seems that mobile browsers take it upon themselves to determine the way a site is displayed. This typically means taking a desktop version of a website and zooming out to fit the contents on the screen. For 90% of the internet this is necessary otherwise the mobile browsing experience would be horrifying. For responsive websites this is no good because in most cases we have very specific elements that must be altered depending on the resolution of the device the site is being viewed on. So how do we stop the browsers from doing this?

By using a viewport meta tag. The standard tag looks something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

But there are a lot of different ways you can customize this to suit your needs. A good reference is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag